# Usernames in search result are bold

Tags: bug, design

Usernames in search result page are **bold**, but on the question they aren't.

## Search results

[image: baaaddddd]

## Question page

[image: better]

Not only they should be consistent (bold as to indicate... what?), but on a *lighter* background there is no need for the extra contrast from a bold. If anything, it would make more sense to put it on the *darker* background...

Please make them all regular.

---

I see, they are the same as the questions page, but there there is no avatar!

Comment: This is in meta, I haven't checked on main...

Comment: Is this still an issue? Where are you seeing this?